# Excel 2010 VBA - Close file No Save without prompt

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I want to close a Excel 2010 file with VBA..
but when the code runs, it shows a prompt confirmation....
i dont want to see this prompt..

didnt work:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you're not wanting to save changes set savechanges to false

```
    Sub CloseBook2()
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    End Sub
```

for more examples, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213428 and i believe in the past I've just used

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

Comment: but this is for Excel 2007, and i want 2010...

Comment: Both versions still work with Office 2019. Although I would recommend using ```ThisWorkbook.Close False``` instead of ```ActiveWorkbook.Close False```.

Comment: Forgot to mention: if you put your code directly into the workbook module you can of course use ```Me.Close False```.